# Exit with error from subshell

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I have this command:

```
echo $(bash main.sh)
```

In `main.sh`, I run a java program that simply throws an exception immediately. The exit code of echo is 0 which means the command succeeded. Is there anyway to make it fail with the exit code from `bash main.sh`?

The use of `echo` is not mandatory, it can be replaced with another program.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the command substitution in a variable first, which will let you keep the exit code:

```
output=$(bash main.sh)
exit_code=$?

some-command "$output"
(exit "$exit_code") # now $? will have exit status of the script
```

Example:

```
$ foo=$(echo bar; false)
$ ret=$?
$ echo $ret
1
```